# How to call a dialog box from another (Win32 application)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, dialog

I implemented a dialog-based Win32 Visual C++ application *(Visual Studio Ultimate 2012)* by following this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227831/A-dialog-based-Win-C-program).

What is the way to call another dialog box (by clicking on a button) from the one I already created?

Comment: What is the actual problem? What have you tried so far? What is not working for you?  You need to be more specific if you expect to get any help.

Comment: You 're right. The problem is I don't have any particular idea about this implementation and I didn't find any article about this. I'll keep trying and if there is any progress I 'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button to the dialog in the dialog resource view. Just drag a button from the toolbar onto the dialog template. When the button is clicked you will get a WM_COMMAND message containing the button ID and the BN_CLICKED notification code.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Add a case in your DialogProc to detect the click. When you get it, create a new dialog by calling the DialogBox API.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This second dialog will need you to write a new DialogProc2, just like the first DialogProc, to handle messages from the second dialog.